# Java Long primitive type maximum limit

Tags: java

I am using the Long primitive type which increments by 1 whenever my 'generateNumber'method called. What happens if Long reaches to his maximum limit? will throw any exception or will reset to minimum value?
here is my sample code:

```
class LongTest {
   private static long increment;
   public static long generateNumber(){
       ++increment;
       return increment;
   }
}
```

Comment: Pretty big range - `8 bytes signed (two's complement). Ranges from -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to +9,223,372,036,854,775,807.`  http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/02.html

Comment: Once you reached to max value, next it will get rollover to min value.

Answer (score 426, accepted):

`Long.MAX_VALUE` is `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`.

If you were executing your function once per nanosecond, it would still take over 292 years to encounter this situation according to [this source](http://www.google.ca/search?q=9%2C223%2C372%2C036%2C854%2C775%2C807+nanoseconds+in+years).

When that happens, it'll just wrap around to `Long.MIN_VALUE`, or `-9,223,372,036,854,775,808` as others have said.

Comment: That's a hell of a source.

Comment: Least there's a good chance that source won't expire.

Comment: I like the source!!

Comment: 292 Million* years

Comment: @argh1969 - what's your source? That would be true at once per __milli__second...

Comment: And your code will be stopped through an active brain interface before 292 years have passed, no matter where you deploy it.

Comment: [independend source](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=9,223,372,036,854,775,807+nanoseconds+in+years) ;-)

Comment: 9223372036854775807 without commas for people like me who want to copy the number

Comment: @matthew.kempson - I hope nobody ever needs to refer to the raw number in code! The static constant exists so nobody needs to refer to it like that.

Comment: and I was reading a long x long cinemaRoom sometime ago, imagine that

Answer (score 47):

It will overflow and wrap around to `Long.MIN_VALUE`.

Its not too likely though. Even if you increment 1,000,000 times per second it will take about 300,000 years to overflow.

Answer (score 10):

Ranges from -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to +9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

It will start from -9,223,372,036,854,775,808

```
Long.MIN_VALUE.
```

Answer (score 10):

Exceding the maximum value of a long doesnt throw an exception, instead it cicles back. If you do this:

```
Long.MAX_VALUE + 1
```

you will notice that the result is the equivalent to Long.MIN_VALUE.

From here: [java number exceeds long.max_value - how to detect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12348067/java-number-exceeds-long-max-value-how-to-detect)