# Loss of precision multiplying large longs

Tags: java, double, long-integer

I'm working on a problem statement that essentially is a fibonacci sequence:

Given two initial values as inputs, you calculate term x = (term x-1)^2 + (term x-2)

So, given input 0 1 5, we want to calculate term 5 of the sequence, which is done in the following way:

Term 3 = (Term 2)^2+(term 1) = 1^2 + 0 = 1

Term 4 = (Term 3)^3+(term 2) = 1^1 + 1 = 2

Term 5 = 2^2+1 = 5

And so on.

My problem comes when I try to calculate a large value, say the 10th. Using `long`as my data type, I lose precision precisely at the 10th value. The expected/correct value is `84266613096281243382112, but I get..

```
0 1 10
Term number 3 has value 1
Term number 4 has value 2
Term number 5 has value 5
Term number 6 has value 27
Term number 7 has value 734
Term number 8 has value 538783
Term number 9 has value 290287121823
Term number 10 has value 1886167576011600224
```

Doing the same problem using `double`as my data type instead gives me the correct answer, but not in the format I need (this is for an automated test case).

```
0 1 10
Term number 3 has value 1.0
Term number 4 has value 2.0
Term number 5 has value 5.0
Term number 6 has value 27.0
Term number 7 has value 734.0
Term number 8 has value 538783.0
Term number 9 has value 2.90287121823E11
Term number 10 has value 8.426661309628124E22
```

Why am I experiencing this loss of precision with long and how can I prevent it/get my desired output?

Comment: possible duplicate of [java Long primitive type maxumum limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505515/java-long-primitive-type-maxumum-limit)

Answer (score 1):

That is because a [`long`'s max value is 2^63-1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) (or 9.223372e+18). You simply cannot go higher than that.

If `double` is of enough precision for your application, you can look at formatting it as per specification with for instance [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

If `double` is not of sufficient precision you can look at using [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html). But it will come at a much higher performance cost.

Answer (score 1):

Try with BigInteger class, it work:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigInteger x1, x2, x3;

        x1 = new BigInteger("0");
        x2 = new BigInteger("1");

        for (int i = 3; i <= 10; i++){
            x3 = x2.multiply(x2).add(x1);
            System.out.println(i + ":" + x3);
            x1 = x2;
            x2 = x3;
        }
    }

}
```