# BigInteger.pow() doesn't work until last 2 iterations?

Tags: java, biginteger

I have the following code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigInteger iter = BigInteger.valueOf(140);
    BigInteger y = BigInteger.valueOf(1114112);
    BigInteger sum = BigInteger.valueOf(0);
    while(iter.intValue() != 0) {
        BigInteger z = BigInteger.valueOf((y.pow(iter.intValue())).longValue());
        sum = sum.add(z);
        iter = iter.subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(1));
        System.out.println("Itereration: " + (140 - iter.longValue()));
        System.out.println("Y: " + y.longValue());
        System.out.println("Z: " + z.longValue());
        System.out.println("Sum: " + sum.longValue());
   }
}
```

However, the output is this (only last 3 iterations)

```
Iteration: 137
Y: 1114112
Z: 0
Sum: 0
Iteration: 138
Y: 1114112
Z: 1382886560579452928
Sum: 1382886560579452928
Iteration: 139
Y: 1114112
Z: 1241245548544
Sum: 1382887801825001472
Iteration: 140
Y: 1114112
Z: 1114112
Sum: 1382887801826115584
```

The rest of iterations 1-136 are the same as iteration 137

Comment: Side note: why on earth is `iter` a `BigInteger`??

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Stop converting your BigIntegers to longs and ints...

Comment: Possible hint: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15505663/180100

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.longValue()` calls do completely wrong things on `BigInteger` values this large. If you tried using `.longValueExact()` instead, you'd see that it throws an exception because the values are out of range for a `long`. But if you don't do the unnecessary `.longValue()` calls , the code works:

```
BigInteger iter = BigInteger.valueOf(140);
BigInteger y = BigInteger.valueOf(1114112);
BigInteger sum = BigInteger.valueOf(0);
while(iter.intValue() != 0) {
    BigInteger z = y.pow(iter.intValue();
    sum = sum.add(z);
    iter = iter.subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(1));
    System.out.println("Itereration: " + (140 - iter.longValue()));
    System.out.println("Y: " + y);
    System.out.println("Z: " + z);
    System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
}
```

And as @RC. has suggested in the comment, you could make `iter` a simple `int`, which simplifies the code further:

```
int iter = 140;
BigInteger y = BigInteger.valueOf(1114112);
BigInteger sum = BigInteger.valueOf(0);
while(iter != 0) {
    BigInteger z = y.pow(iter);
    sum = sum.add(z);
    iter--;
    System.out.println("Itereration: " + (140 - iter));
    System.out.println("Y: " + y);
    System.out.println("Z: " + z);
    System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that you could just print the BigInteger's value that way.