# Which data type should I use for declaring number equal to 12000000000 in JAVA(JDK1.7)?

Tags: java, integer, long-integer, biginteger, jdk1.7

After using class BigInteger my program on platform showed Memory Limit Exceeded.

Comment: What does "didn't work" look like?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505515/java-long-primitive-type-maximum-limit

Comment: 12000000000 is well within the range of a `long`. Did you remember to append `L` to it?

Comment: Why didn't a long work?

Comment: 12000000000 would take less than 15 bytes of memory.

Comment: Please read  [mcve]. If your code isn't working, post it here. If using BigInteger leads to OutOfMemory exceptions, then most likely the problem isn't caused by using BigInteger. But by doing something else seriously wrong.

Comment: If 12000000000 would cause OutOfMemory then majority of programs around wouldn't have worked which deals with bigger number than this. There must be some other part in your program causing this error.

Comment: As well as BigInteger is completely fine too. Actually BigInteger has no value limit as Long does. It just uses more memory something around 60 - 100 bytes as I remember... Maybe problem is not about type you use but about how many values are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long can handle that value. You should remember to type an L after the value. For example:

```
long value = 12000000000L;
```

In the other hand, there is no limit for the BigInteger in theory due to it allocates the memory amount it needs, **the limit is the available memory**. You need to keep in mind BigInteger class is inmutable, so if you call add, multiply, divide or whatever it will return a new BigInteger instead of modifying the current one.
You may consider to implement your own data structure according to your needs. And also you may consider to post your code.

Comment: BigInteger is a class so on calling, platform gives Memory Limit Exceeded. 
Sorry! Next Time I will post my code.
(Platform: online coding practice)

Answer (score 1):

The maximal value a long can save (Long.MAX_VALUE) is `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`. As you say you want to save a number equal to `12,000,000,000` it should be totally possible to save it using a long, because your number is still much smaller that Long.MAX_VALUE...