# How can I create a big loop like from 0 to range of Long?

Tags: java

The below given code is taking so much time to execute code correct answer

```
for(long i=0;i<9223372036854775807;i++){
   //code
}
```

Can anyone tell me any alternative approach or correction of this version?

Comment: You could use Long.MAX_VALUE

Comment: Why would you want to loop that many times anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one change you could make is to use the constant Long.MAX_VALUE instead.

But don't expect that to change anything. That loop still takes all the time it takes to iterate that range.

In other words: how you express "I want to iterate 2 to the power of 63 minus 1" times doesn't influence the time required to do that at all.

The only thing to cut runtime is by slicing the range and have multiple smaller loops go in parallel. But of course: without any detail on the loop body it is not possible to determine whether parallelism is applicable here.

And of course, the real question would be about the actual problem that you intend to solve by iterating code for millions, billions of years.

Answer (score 2):

from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15505663/7806805
and since your question is

> The below given code is taking so much time to execute code correct answer

*If you were executing your function once per nanosecond, it would still take over 292 years to encounter this situation according to this source.*

so its natural for it to take time

Comment: Then what is alternative approach I can use rather than this?

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to use `Long.MAX_VALUE` as a loop bound:

```
for(long i=0L;i<Long.MAX_VALUE;i++){
//code
  }
```

Comment: You pretty much just said what Shar1er80 said in his comment.

Comment: The OP's concern is that his program is taking too much time. Not this.

Comment: @LAD to be honset, I didn't copy his comment :D

Comment: Yeah that's pretty obvious, for sure, it'll take a huge time to be done.