# Limit for no of messages in a topic partition

Tags: apache-kafka

Is there a limit for total no of messages (or records or offsets) within a partition in a topic? I know there is a max. message size limit we can set either per partition or at broker level but I want to know if there is a no of limit for total no or max no of messages within a particular partition.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a theoretical limit. Kafka stores offsets as a Java `Long`. Therefore, I'd assume it's around `Long.MAX_VALUE`, but it [would take years for you to really reach it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505515/java-long-primitive-type-maximum-limit).